# I don't know what is wrong with this MCMF code

Tags: c++

I'm studying MCMF(Minimum Cost - Maximum Flow) algorithm.

I finish to code my MCMF code but it continues to occur runtime error.

and I can't find the reasons.

I tried best to find the reason why it happens, but I couldn't find the solution.

I think there is no problem with my input data.

Here is my code.

```cpp
struct MCMF{
    struct edge{
        int to, cap, cost, rev;
    };
    int size, src, sink;
    vector<vector<edge> > G;
    vector<int> dist, par, edgeIdx;
    MCMF(int size, int src, int sink){
        G = vector<vector<edge> >(size);
        par = vector<int>(size);
        edgeIdx = vector<int>(size);
        this->size = size;
        this->src = src;
        this->sink = sink;
    }
    bool spfa(){
        dist = vector<int>(size, inf);
        vector<bool> inQ = vector<bool>(size, false);
        queue<int> q;
        q.push(src);
        inQ[src] = true;
        dist[src] = 0;
        while(!q.empty()){
            int here = q.front();
            q.pop();
            inQ[here] = false;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)G[here].size(); i++){
                auto e = G[here][i];
                if(e.cap > 0 && dist[here] + e.cost < dist[e.to]) {
                    dist[e.to] = dist[here] + e.cost;
                    par[e.to] = here;
                    edgeIdx[e.to] = i;
                    if(!inQ[e.to]) q.push(e.to), inQ[e.to] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return dist[sink] != inf;
    }
    pair<int,int> getMCMF(){
        int maxFlow = 0;
        int minCost = 0;
        while(1){
            if(!spfa()) break;
            int minFlow = inf;
            int costSum = 0;
            for(int p = sink; p != par[p]; p = par[p]){
                auto& e = G[par[p]][edgeIdx[p]];
                minFlow = min(minFlow, e.cap);
                costSum += e.cost;
            }
            for(int p = sink; p != par[p]; p = par[p]){
                auto& e = G[par[p]][edgeIdx[p]];
                e.cap -= minFlow;
                G[e.to][e.rev].cap += minFlow;
            }
            maxFlow += minFlow;
            minCost += costSum * minFlow;
        }
        return {maxFlow, minCost};
    }
    void addEdge(int from, int to, int cap, int cost){
        G[from].push_back({to, cap, cost, (int)G[to].size()});
        G[to].push_back({from, 0, -cost, (int)G[from].size()-1});
    }
};
```

Comment: *I think there is no problem with my input data.* - Please provide this data, and a `main` program.  That way, you will be sure that others can duplicate the error and suggest what is wrong (instead of eyeballing code, running the program in their head, and hope what they tell you is correct).

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE], then edit your question to provide the missing bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add the code

```
par[src] = src
```

if you don't want to change

```
for(int p = sink; p != par[p]; p = par[p])
```

and I think it's better if you change

```
p != par[p]
```

to

```
p != src
```

in your for loop.

because It's more clear to understand the code and you don't have to add 'par[src] = src'

Here is the full code if you correct the parts what I said

```cpp
struct MCMF{
    struct edge{
        int to, cap, cost, rev;
    };
    int size, src, sink;
    vector<vector<edge> > G;
    vector<int> dist, par, edgeIdx;
    MCMF(int size, int src, int sink){
        G = vector<vector<edge> >(size);
        par = vector<int>(size);
        edgeIdx = vector<int>(size);
        this->size = size;
        this->src = src;
        this->sink = sink;
    }
    bool spfa(){
        dist = vector<int>(size, inf);
        vector<bool> inQ = vector<bool>(size, false);
        queue<int> q;
        q.push(src);
        inQ[src] = true;
        dist[src] = 0;
        while(!q.empty()){
            int here = q.front();
            q.pop();
            inQ[here] = false;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)G[here].size(); i++){
                auto e = G[here][i];
                if(e.cap > 0 && dist[here] + e.cost < dist[e.to]) {
                    dist[e.to] = dist[here] + e.cost;
                    par[e.to] = here;
                    edgeIdx[e.to] = i;
                    if(!inQ[e.to]) q.push(e.to), inQ[e.to] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return dist[sink] != inf;
    }
    pair<int,int> getMCMF(){
        int maxFlow = 0;
        int minCost = 0;
        while(1){
            if(!spfa()) break;
            int minFlow = inf;
            int costSum = 0;
            for(int p = sink; p != src; p = par[p]){
                auto& e = G[par[p]][edgeIdx[p]];
                minFlow = min(minFlow, e.cap);
                costSum += e.cost;
            }
            for(int p = sink; p != src; p = par[p]){
                auto& e = G[par[p]][edgeIdx[p]];
                e.cap -= minFlow;
                G[e.to][e.rev].cap += minFlow;
            }
            maxFlow += minFlow;
            minCost += costSum * minFlow;
        }
        return {maxFlow, minCost};
    }
    void addEdge(int from, int to, int cap, int cost){
        G[from].push_back({to, cap, cost, (int)G[to].size()});
        G[to].push_back({from, 0, -cost, (int)G[from].size()-1});
    }
};
```